# Count Unique Values Based On Multiple Criteria - BOOLEAN not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Trying to count unique values with below formula. It returns #value!. There are 4 criteria (two dates and two other criteria)

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((MONTH('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!E1:E5000)=MONTH("1-1-2020"))*(YEAR('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!E1:E5000)=YEAR("1-1-2020"))*('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!H1:H5000="PRO TW");MATCH('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!F1:F5000;'DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!F1:F5000));ROW('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!F1:F5000)-ROW('DK BLD QUOTES - APP'!$F$2)+1)>0))
```

Can someone find the mistake?

Comment: Did you array-enter it? Have you tried the Formula Evaluation tool?

Comment: Yes did array-enter. Formula tool not tried yet.

Comment: Why use the MONTH and YEAR functions with static dates, when you could just use 1 and 2020 directly? (I assume  your regional settings use the `-` as a date separator? If not, that would explain the error.) Do you have a header row, or blank cells in the date column range?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Should I be using date function instead?

Comment: No, just use the actual month and year numbers. You didn't answer my other questions though which I suspect are more relevant.

Comment: Yes, my regional settings use - as separator.
Yes, I have header row and also blank cells.

Comment: If you have a header row, then don't include row 1 in your ranges.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. Now the formula returns a result. But the result is wrong.